# Training set, validation set, and test set with Orange

Tags: training, orange

Is it possible with Orange (only using its widgets, without writing Python code) to implement the following typical machine learning processes?

1. Train a training set,
2. Validating a validation set (e.g. using k-fold cross validation), and
3. Testing the model with a test set.

Using the 'Test & Score" widget, a single dataset is used. Does this mean that only validation is performed, and there is no actual test? Can in this case classification results (accuracy, AUC, etc.) considered reliable?

Comment: Disclaimer. I've never use Orange myself. Still, a quick look at online documentation suggests (and that would be no surprise) that is has all the tools you're looking for. https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/evaluation/testandscore.html

Comment: I keep getting "test and train datasets have different target variables" error message. This is despite using exact same formats and names (with different values of course). What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. If Test & Score is given only one data set, then all it can do is show results of cross-validation.

To test the models on a separate data set, use separate File widgets to load training and test data. Connect File widget with training data to Test & Score, and the connect File widget with Test data to Test & Score. The connect whatever learner to test (in the workflow on the figure I've used logistic regression and random forest). Make sure "Test on train data" is selected in the Test & Score.

[image: Orange workflo with Test & Score widget]

Comment: How can i then check accuracy of best model in test set and then save it for use external to Orange

Answer (score 0):

In the case of image classification,[image] training and testing on different data sets could be achieved with the attached configuration? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use the widget "Save model" to save the model that you've created and "load Model" to validate on new set of data.

[image]